# Convert Object into array,angular JS 1.X

Tags: angularjs

I want to convert the below object in an array. object is as like below,

```
       var obj = {
               "abfdgc" :"def",
               "dfdgsf" : "ret",
               "trytr"  : "dhgf"
       }
```

into below format :

```
       var obj = [{
               "abfdgc" :"def",
               "dfdgsf" : "ret",
               "trytr"  : "dhgf"
       }]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go, as simple as:

```
obj = [obj];
```